# Mongoid+Rails: Atomic callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, callback, mongoid, atomic

I know that in Rails all ActiveRecord callbacks are executed inside transaction. So if something goes wrong nothing is changed/wrong. Will Mongoid gem handle this in the same way (no transactions available as far as I know)?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a transaction in mongodb, so no this won't be handled for you. Should something blow up in an `after_save` or something like that you'll need to fix the damage yourself.

The general approach (as the [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-do-transactions-and-locking-in-mongodb) hints at) is to try and design around this by using mongo's atomic modifiers.